# How to determine the amount of time between two datetime objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, time

I am trying to find the amount of years, months, days, etc between two `datetime` objects. I know I can use`timedelta` to find a date x days after a previously specified date, but I want to take two `datetime` objects and find the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract them

```
date1 - date2
```

which gives you a `timedelta`.

Comment: Note: There is no such thing as a canonical year (thanks to leap years) or months (because they range from 28-31 days). The `timedelta` can give you the total number of seconds, the number of whole days, the number of seconds less than a whole day, and the number of microseconds less than a complete second, but you'll need to come up with your own definition of years or months (and it won't be portable in most cases).

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you know if there is a way to get the number of months using timedelta? I can't divide the days by 30 because that won't account for February or months with 31 days. Edit: Just saw that comment after I posted. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
import datetime
date1 = datetime.datetime.now()
```

lots of time passes...

```
date2 = datetime.datetime.now()
Nmonths = date2.month - date1.month
```

Some other things to consider:

```
Nseconds = date2.second - date1.second
Nminutes = date2.minute - date2.second
```